# Is AMD (Lazyloading) really efficient?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading, amd

I been developing a single page application which has become really huge now. I started off with Require JS and AngularJS, but there are too many components and loading a single page would make around 40-50 requests to the server (including template files).

Even if the data is cached for all future requests, sending 40-50 requests for the first attempt turns out to be quite expensive and awfully slow on slower internet connections.

My understanding is that if we concatenate and create two script files - `Vendors.js` (the doesn't change very often) and `Private.js` (changes with every release) the page load times would be much faster. If this is true then why would someone even use requirejs at all?

Answer (score 4):

You can only compare efficiency, not make absolute claims about it. So you will need to ask

> Is sending 40-50 requests more efficient than 1 request for a concatenated file?

No, definitely not. While you might get little advantages because of parallelisation (unlikely still), the overhead is just to much.

> Is not requiring an unneeded file more efficient than always loading the file?

Yes, it obviously is.

And that's what *lazy* loading is all about: It request files only when they are needed, instead of prematurely downloading everything.

So, for a fast app you need to determine which ressources are always (or most often) needed, and concatenate them to one file. The other modules that are seldom needed can go on their own. Taking caching of changing ressources into consideration like you did allows for further optimisation.

> why would someone even use AMD at all?

Because it embraces modularisation. Also, it enables very flexible deployment strategies - from serving every module independently in development to using optimisers for production. Without changing your code files.

Comment: I like your answer ... It adds a new perspective

Comment: Modularization can be achieved via angular's dependency injection module. Which also assists in unit testing. I asked the question to make sure that there isn't any aspect of AMD that I am being ignorant about. You covered all the points, thus making my decision of going with the Concatination approach, considering this scenario, more confident. Thanks!